# text replace in xml using ant

Tags: ant

I want to change the version number in a xml file using ant.
I tried ant's replace task but it's not working.

The xml file I have looks like this.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org<br>/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

Comment: "I tried ant's replace task but it's not working." What is not working? Do you get an error? Or is the wrong text replaced? Or...? Please be more specific.

Comment: BTW: Your xml is missing some closing tags `</groupId>`, `</artifactId>`.

Comment: Your `ant` xml file is actually a **maven** pom.xml  - you seem to be mixing up your tutorials. Ant and Maven are two different build systems completely.

Answer (score 4):

You can use copy task.
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html

abc.template.xml:

```
<abc version="@VERSION@">
   <item name="xxxxx"/>
</abc>
```

ant_script:

```
<copy file="abc.template.xml"
tofile="abc.xml"
filtering="yes" overwrite="yes">
<filterset>
    <filter token="VERSION" value="1.0"/>
</filterset>
</copy>
```

Comment: Agreed I use this approach when generating Maven POM files

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it appears your problem is caused by wrong file or wrong syntax.

I have below content in my pom.xml:

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>@VERSION</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  </project>
```

See below my build.xml

```
<project name="Test" default="replaceContent" basedir=".">
<target name="replaceContent">
        <replace file="src/pom.xml" token="@VERSION" value="5.0.0.0"/>
    </target>
    </project>
```

Now If i run $ ant replaceContent, it replace my token @VERSION with whatever i specify in build file as 'value'. So after successful execution, `<modelVersion>` value in pom.xml will change to 5.0.0.0

Next time when you post any question, also mention details of error.